# Computing the length of a module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I have some trouble to compute the length of the $\mathbb{R}[x]$-module $M=\mathbb{C}[x]/\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Usually, I would try to find a composition series of the module, but I am not sure how to find submodules of $M$. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Notice that C[x] has a direct sum decomposition as an R[x]-module of the form $\mathbb R[x]\oplus i\mathbb R[x]$. Your quotient is thus infinite dimensional and, since the simple R[x]-modules have dimension 1 or 2, is of infinite length.

Comment: I see. My first thought was also that the length is infinite. But I thought of using that $\text{length}(M)=\text{length}(\mathbb{C}[x])-\text{length}(\mathbb{R}[x])$ and then noticing that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is not Artinian and therefore has infinite length. Would this argument also be valid?

Comment: Yes, but if $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is not Artinian, then $M$ can also not be Artinian and must therefore have infinite length. I use the fact that submodules of Artinian modules are Artinian.

Comment: That is strange. I use Theorem 12.3 from the book "A Course in Commutative Algebra" and there is no such an hypothesis. In the proof is written that if the submodule has infinite length, the module has infinite length too.

Comment: Yes, the exact equality is Len(M)=Len(N)+Len(M/N).

Comment: I cite the part of the proof in the book: "If length(N) = ∞ or length(M/N) = ∞, then by part (b) at least one of these modules fails to be Noetherian or Artinian, so by Proposition 2.4 the same is true for M, and length(M) = ∞, too."

Comment: Part (b) is the one who says that the length is finite if the module is Noetherian and Artinian. And Prop. 2.4 is the one where submodules of Artinian modules are Artinian.

Comment: I agree with you that this part confused me. That's why I asked this question in the first place. I was hoping to get a different argument.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I gather that OP wants a way to explicitly see that $M$ is of infinite length, rather than arguing abstractly.

Let us show that $M\cong\mathbb{R}[x]$ as $\mathbb{R}[x]$-modules. Indeed, we have a map $\Im:\mathbb{C}[x]\to \mathbb{R}[x]$ defined by $\sum_{i\geq 0}p_ix^i\mapsto \sum_{i\geq 0}\Im(p_i)x^i$ (where $\Im(z)$ is the imaginary part of a complex number $z$). This map is easily checked to be an $\mathbb{R}[x]$-module homomorphism, which moreover is surjective. Furthermore, its kernel is precisely $\mathbb{R}[x]\subseteq \mathbb{C}[x]$, so we obtain $M\cong \mathbb{R}[x]$. So the submodules of $M$ are in an inclusion-preserving one-to-one correspondence with the submodules of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ (explicity, a submodule $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}[x]$ corresponds to $(\mathbb{R}[x]+i\cdot I)/\mathbb{R}[x]\subseteq M$). As $\mathbb{R}[x]$ isn't Artinian, we obtain that $M$ has infinite length.

Maybe to resolve the discussion in the comments: if we allow the quantities to be infinite, the formula $\operatorname{length}(M)=\operatorname{length}(N)+\operatorname{length}(M/N)$ *isn't* equivalent to the formula $\operatorname{length}(M/N)=\operatorname{length}(M)-\operatorname{length}(M)$. The former holds also for infinite quantities (as it makes sense to define $\infty+\text{something}=\infty$), but the latter makes no sense in certain cases (as one cannot sensibly define $\infty-\infty$).